# How do you restric maximum length of elements in language of context free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-sensitive-grammar

How does one restrict the maximum length of elements in a context free grammar.... How would you structure rules to say only allow for elements of language to be of length seven and less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you can even express it as a REGEX/FSA. All you need to do is essentially the same thing as you would in those machines, which is to make `n` amount of nodes which in your case 7. Basically it looks like this.

```
R -> <1><2>...<7>

<1> -> elements. | e
<2> -> elements. | e
..
<7> -> elements. | e
```

Comment: Thank you.... My question was not specific enough though. so how would I allow for a length of between a range. say 3 to 7.

Comment: for what I have in mind it would look like R= <S><S><S><S><S><S><S>

Comment: @MokgadiRasekgala you just need to not have 3 of them include the empty terminator.

Comment: Im guessing you meant not include the empty terminator??? so redefine S twice as S1-> a,b,c,   and S2->a,b,c,empty and have something like R=<S1><S1><S1><S2><S2><S2><S2>

Comment: or rather just S2->S1,e